# Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined (onclick.toString())

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the source code of Javascript function corresponding to onclick event.
I'm getting an error if there is a single quote (') inside the onclick function.
Following is the sample code,

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            function selectedInputChange(input, mode, auth) {
            }
            function onClickToString() {
                try {
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('radioSelect').onclick.toString();
                }
                catch(err) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
        <input type="radio" id="radioSelect" onclick="selectedInputChange('Some input with ' in it')"/>
        <button type="button" onclick="onClickToString()">Click Here</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If there were no single quote present then I'm getting proper output but if there is a single quote I'm getting

> Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

error response, how to get the string even if there is a single quote?

**Edit**
Note: I don't have the control over the HTML content, I'm simply loading a web page inside an iframe, which gives me the above HTML source.
So as per one of the comment it is not a typo.

Comment: You can not get binded handler in this way .

Comment: It's just a typo, missing backslash.

Comment: No its not, the whole content will be inside an iframe and we don't have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "onclick" is not object, just event.
If you want getting onclick's inner string value,you can get by "getAttribute".

```
document.getElementById('radioSelect').getAttribute("onclick");
```

About getAttribute 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: What if there are multiple radio selects with each having different input in onclick?

Answer (score 0):

This attribute contains invalid JavaScript (JavaScript with a syntax error in it):

```
// JavaScript string ends here ---------------v
onclick="selectedInputChange('Some input with ' in it')"
// So this is a syntax error ------------------^^^^^^^^
```

You need a backslash on that contained single quote:

```
onclick="selectedInputChange('Some input with \' in it')"
```

which works:

```js
function selectedInputChange() {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('radioSelect').onclick.toString();
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radioSelect" onclick="selectedInputChange('Some input with \' in it')"/>
<p id="demo"></p>
```